# Why does GTalk disconnect and block for 10 minutes after client sends presence, type=subscribe?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I have googled significantly and quite sure this has not been asked before.
The issue is very specific to GTalk's XMPP.

When I send

`<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="requester@gmail.com/mybotFFF6F83D" to="user@gmail.com" type="subscribe" id="13.562074535344ce3d41a7ba07"/>`

GTalk returns `</stream:stream>` and keeps returning it for 10 minutes if the client tries to reconnect. After 10 minutes, everything goes back to normal and the client works again. There isn't any error code or such. Any idea why?

#### Update

I went through several other clients, including Google's own Gtalk for Windows desktop and they all exhibit the same behavior (unable to connect for 10 minutes after adding a contact). Does anybody know why or where I can report it to them? Thanks.

Comment: It is uncommon to include an `id` attribute on `presence` stanzas (even though RFC 6120 says that it's "RECOMMENDED").  Does it happen if you leave out the `id`?

Comment: you are fast. let me try and update shortly

Comment: ```<presence xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" to="user@gmail.com" type="subscribe" from="requester@gmail.com/mybotA26F8B0F"/>``` I sent this, and still the same reaction from the server